# Firebase Client ID needed for Braintree’s PayPal Integration

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, paypal, braintree

I have went through the Firebase & Braintree docs, but their is no solutions. I’m trying to setup Braintree on Firebase, and it’s saying I need a client id from Firebase but I’m having trouble getting it and storing it in Braintree.

Anyone ever did this before? It’s an iOS app, using Firebase, and Braintree (PayPal) for peer to peer transactions.